# Trouble getting the final path for Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding, backtracking

I have been self-teaching myself AI by recreating path finding algorithms (so no, it's not an assignment or anything), more specifically Dijkstra, and managed to get everything in the beginning to work (algorithm expands exactly like Dijkstra and can determine the weight of the shortest path). However I am struggling with coming up with the backtracking part in which it takes that shortest path and return the verticies

I read a lot and studied a lot about the Dijkstra tables and fully understand it conceptually (I can solve a lot of problems correctly involving Dijkstra tables) but I have trouble translating the backtracking part in which it returns the vertices of the shortest path.

Anyone mind giving me some guidance here?

Code:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heappushpop
import collections
import copy

def min_val(destVal, marked, target_edge):
    if(destVal > marked + target_edge):
        destVal = marked + target_edge
        return destVal
    else:
        return destVal

def weighted(graph, start, end):

true_graph = copy.deepcopy(graph)

current_min_distance = 0
trail = []
trail_value =[0]
to_expand = collections.deque()
to_expand_list = []
to_expand_list_value = []
new_node = start
trail.append(start)
destVal_node = []
destVal_value = []
full_destVal = {}
parents = {}
print "Starting point: ", graph[start]
lowest_distance = 0;

while True:
    mindistance = float("inf")
    table_check = []
    table_check_values = []
    print "____________________________________"


    to_remove = []
    starting_node = new_node

    minigraph = graph[new_node]
    print "Starting point: ", new_node
    print "Graph of current node: ", graph[new_node]


    print "To expand beginning: ", to_expand
    table_check = full_destVal.keys()
    table_check_values = full_destVal.values()

    for node in to_expand:


        if node not in minigraph:
            minigraph[node] = full_to_expand.get(node)

    full_trail = dict(zip(trail, trail_value))        
    full_to_expand = dict(zip(to_expand_list, to_expand_list_value))


    if new_node == end:
        print ""
        print ""
        print "**********************************Soulution Found**********************************"
        print ""
        print "Trail: ", trail
        print "Parents: ", parents
        print "Length of shortest path: ", lowest_distance

        solution = [end]
        n = end

        while n in parents and parents[n]:
            solution.append(parents[n])
            n = parents[n]

        return solution[::-1]

    #Goes through each node in the minigraph
    for node in minigraph:
        full_to_expand = dict(zip(to_expand_list, to_expand_list_value))

        if node not in to_expand and node not in trail:
            to_expand.append(node)
            to_expand_list.append(node)
            print minigraph
            to_expand_list_value.append(minigraph[node])



        if node not in trail and to_expand:
            parents[node] = new_node
            mindistance = float("inf")
            if node in full_destVal:
                mindistance = full_destVal[node]
            else:
                minidistance = float("inf")
            heappush(q, minigraph[node])
            full_to_expand = dict(zip(to_expand_list, to_expand_list_value))
            to_compare = min_val(mindistance, int(full_trail.get(starting_node)), int(minigraph[node]))
            table_check.append(node)
            table_check_values.append(to_compare)
            full_table_check = dict(zip(table_check, table_check_values))
            to_expand_list_value[to_expand_list.index(node)] = to_compare
            mindistance = min(table_check_values)
            new_node = table_check[table_check_values.index(min(table_check_values))]         
            if new_node not in trail:
                trail_value.append(min(table_check_values))
                trail.append(new_node)
    full_trail = dict(zip(trail, trail_value))        
    full_destVal = dict(zip(table_check, table_check_values))
    lowest_distance = mindistance

    print "Chosen node:", mindistance
    print "Node to visit: ", new_node
    print "Complete trail of nodes visited ",full_trail
    print "Full to_expand_list: ", full_to_expand
    print "Current minigraph",minigraph


    full_destVal.pop(new_node, None)
    table_check = full_destVal.keys()
    table_check_values = full_destVal.values()

    full_to_expand.pop(new_node, None)
    to_expand_list = full_to_expand.keys()
    to_expand_list_value = full_to_expand.values()



#Sample weighted graphs

graph = {'A': {'B':4, 'C':3, 'D': 6},
     'B': {'A':3, 'D':8},
     'C': {'D':7, 'E':5},
     'D': {'E':1},
     'E':{}}

grid = {'A': {'B':16, 'C':9, 'D': 35},
     'B': {'A':16, 'D':12, 'E':25},
     'C': {'A':9, 'D':15, 'F':22},
     'D': {'A':35,'B':12,'C':15,'E':14,'F':17, 'G':19},
     'E':{'B':25, 'D':14, 'G':8,},
    'F': {'C':22,'D':17,'G':14},
    'G': {'D':19,'E':8,'F':14},
    }

jim = {
'B': {'A': 5, 'D': 1, 'G': 2},
'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 12, 'F' :5},
'D': {'B': 1, 'G': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 3},
'G': {'B': 2, 'D': 1, 'C': 2},
'C': {'G': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 16},
'E': {'A': 12, 'D': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 2},
'F': {'A': 5, 'E': 2, 'C': 16}}



#print weighted(graph, 'A','E')

print weighted(grid, 'A','G')

#print weighted(jim, 'A','G')
```

Comment: In short: store previous pointers with the latest previous nodes. In the end you can backtrack using these since they contain the values of the last, optimal path, starting from the end of course since that's where you "are".